# DataNode are going in CrashBackLoopOff in HA HDFS

Tags: kubernetes, hdfs

I am deploying HA-HDFS in Kubernetes Cluster. My K8S-cluster architecture is One Master Node and Two Worker Nodes.
My HDFS has two namenodes, One active node, and one standBy Node. 3 datanodes, 3 zookeepers, 3 JounralNodes.
My DataNodes goes to running state and then to CrashLoopBackOff.
Here are logs for dataNode.

```
Configuring core
 - Setting hadoop.proxyuser.hue.hosts=*
 - Setting fs.defaultFS=hdfs://namenode:8020
 - Setting ha.zookeeper.quorum=zookepper-0:2181,zookepper-1:2181,zookepper-2:2181
 - Setting hadoop.http.staticuser.user=root
 - Setting io.compression.codecs=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec
 - Setting hadoop.proxyuser.zeppelin.hosts=*
 - Setting hadoop.proxyuser.zeppelin.groups=*
 - Setting hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups=*
Configuring hdfs
 - Setting dfs.datanode.data.dir=file:///hadoop/dfs/data
 - Setting dfs.namenode.datanode.registration.ip-hostname-check=false
 - Setting dfs.webhdfs.enabled=true
/entrypoint.sh: line 28: HDFS_CONF_dfs_ha_automatic-failover_enabled: bad substitution
Configuring yarn
 - Setting yarn.timeline-service.enabled=true
 - Setting yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.maximum-allocation-vcores=4
 - Setting yarn.resourcemanager.system-metrics-publisher.enabled=true
 - Setting yarn.resourcemanager.store.class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.FileSystemRMStateStore
 - Setting yarn.nodemanager.disk-health-checker.max-disk-utilization-per-disk-percentage=98.5
 - Setting yarn.log.server.url=http://historyserver:8188/applicationhistory/logs/
 - Setting yarn.resourcemanager.fs.state-store.uri=/rmstate
 - Setting yarn.timeline-service.generic-application-history.enabled=true
 - Setting yarn.log-aggregation-enable=true
 - Setting yarn.resourcemanager.hostname=resourcemanager
 - Setting yarn.scheduler.capacity.root.default.maximum-allocation-mb=8192
 - Setting yarn.nodemanager.aux-services=mapreduce_shuffle
 - Setting yarn.resourcemanager.resource_tracker.address=resourcemanager:8031
 - Setting yarn.timeline-service.hostname=historyserver
 - Setting yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address=resourcemanager:8030
 - Setting yarn.resourcemanager.address=resourcemanager:8032
 - Setting mapred.map.output.compress.codec=org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec
 - Setting yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir=/app-logs
 - Setting yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class=org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler
 - Setting mapreduce.map.output.compress=true
 - Setting yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb=16384
 - Setting yarn.resourcemanager.recovery.enabled=true
 - Setting yarn.nodemanager.resource.cpu-vcores=8
Configuring httpfs
Configuring kms
Configuring mapred
 - Setting mapreduce.map.java.opts=-Xmx3072m
 - Setting mapreduce.reduce.java.opts=-Xmx6144m
 - Setting mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb=8192
 - Setting yarn.app.mapreduce.am.env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/
 - Setting mapreduce.map.memory.mb=4096
 - Setting mapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx4096m
 - Setting mapreduce.reduce.env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/
 - Setting mapreduce.framework.name=yarn
 - Setting mapreduce.map.env=HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/
Configuring for multihomed network
2021-08-02 12:17:25,734 INFO datanode.DataNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2021-08-02 12:17:26,724 INFO checker.ThrottledAsyncChecker: Scheduling a check for [DISK]file:/hadoop/dfs/data
2021-08-02 12:17:27,020 INFO impl.MetricsConfig: Loaded properties from hadoop-metrics2.properties
2021-08-02 12:17:27,170 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: Scheduled Metric snapshot period at 10 second(s).
2021-08-02 12:17:27,170 INFO impl.MetricsSystemImpl: DataNode metrics system started
2021-08-02 12:17:27,565 INFO common.Util: dfs.datanode.fileio.profiling.sampling.percentage set to 0. Disabling file IO profiling
2021-08-02 12:17:27,572 INFO datanode.BlockScanner: Initialized block scanner with targetBytesPerSec 1048576
2021-08-02 12:17:27,583 INFO datanode.DataNode: Configured hostname is datanode-1.datanode.hdfs.svc.cluster.local
2021-08-02 12:17:27,583 INFO common.Util: dfs.datanode.fileio.profiling.sampling.percentage set to 0. Disabling file IO profiling
2021-08-02 12:17:27,590 INFO datanode.DataNode: Starting DataNode with maxLockedMemory = 0
2021-08-02 12:17:27,631 INFO datanode.DataNode: Opened streaming server at /0.0.0.0:9866
2021-08-02 12:17:27,636 INFO datanode.DataNode: Balancing bandwidth is 10485760 bytes/s
2021-08-02 12:17:27,636 INFO datanode.DataNode: Number threads for balancing is 50
2021-08-02 12:17:27,734 INFO util.log: Logging initialized @3185ms
2021-08-02 12:17:27,929 INFO server.AuthenticationFilter: Unable to initialize FileSignerSecretProvider, falling back to use random secrets.
2021-08-02 12:17:27,934 INFO http.HttpRequestLog: Http request log for http.requests.datanode is not defined
2021-08-02 12:17:27,947 INFO http.HttpServer2: Added global filter 'safety' (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.HttpServer2$QuotingInputFilter)
2021-08-02 12:17:27,951 INFO http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context datanode
2021-08-02 12:17:27,951 INFO http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context static
2021-08-02 12:17:27,951 INFO http.HttpServer2: Added filter static_user_filter (class=org.apache.hadoop.http.lib.StaticUserWebFilter$StaticUserFilter) to context logs
2021-08-02 12:17:27,990 INFO http.HttpServer2: Jetty bound to port 42767
2021-08-02 12:17:27,992 INFO server.Server: jetty-9.3.24.v20180605, build timestamp: 2018-06-05T17:11:56Z, git hash: 84205aa28f11a4f31f2a3b86d1bba2cc8ab69827
2021-08-02 12:17:28,064 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@5038d0b5{/logs,file:///opt/hadoop-3.2.1/logs/,AVAILABLE}
2021-08-02 12:17:28,065 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.s.ServletContextHandler@2ad48653{/static,file:///opt/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/hdfs/webapps/static/,AVAILABLE}
2021-08-02 12:17:28,224 INFO handler.ContextHandler: Started o.e.j.w.WebAppContext@68034211{/,file:///opt/hadoop-3.2.1/share/hadoop/hdfs/webapps/datanode/,AVAILABLE}{/datanode}
2021-08-02 12:17:28,236 INFO server.AbstractConnector: Started ServerConnector@275bf9b3{HTTP/1.1,[http/1.1]}{localhost:42767}
2021-08-02 12:17:28,237 INFO server.Server: Started @3688ms
2021-08-02 12:17:28,596 INFO web.DatanodeHttpServer: Listening HTTP traffic on /0.0.0.0:9864
2021-08-02 12:17:28,606 INFO util.JvmPauseMonitor: Starting JVM pause monitor
2021-08-02 12:17:28,617 INFO datanode.DataNode: dnUserName = root
2021-08-02 12:17:28,618 INFO datanode.DataNode: supergroup = supergroup
2021-08-02 12:17:28,734 INFO ipc.CallQueueManager: Using callQueue: class java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue, queueCapacity: 1000, scheduler: class org.apache.hadoop.ipc.DefaultRpcScheduler, ipcBackoff: false.
2021-08-02 12:17:28,759 INFO ipc.Server: Starting Socket Reader #1 for port 9867
2021-08-02 12:17:29,162 INFO datanode.DataNode: Opened IPC server at /0.0.0.0:9867
2021-08-02 12:17:29,192 INFO datanode.DataNode: Refresh request received for nameservices: null
2021-08-02 12:17:29,210 INFO datanode.DataNode: Starting BPOfferServices for nameservices: <default>
2021-08-02 12:17:29,230 INFO datanode.DataNode: Block pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to namenode/10.108.44.52:8020 starting to offer service
2021-08-02 12:17:29,240 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server Responder: starting
2021-08-02 12:17:29,241 INFO ipc.Server: IPC Server listener on 9867: starting
2021-08-02 12:17:29,538 INFO datanode.DataNode: Acknowledging ACTIVE Namenode during handshakeBlock pool <registering> (Datanode Uuid unassigned) service to namenode/10.108.44.52:8020
2021-08-02 12:17:29,544 INFO common.Storage: Using 1 threads to upgrade data directories (dfs.datanode.parallel.volumes.load.threads.num=1, dataDirs=1)
2021-08-02 12:17:30,343 INFO common.Storage: Lock on /hadoop/dfs/data/in_use.lock acquired by nodename 378@datanode-1.datanode.hdfs.svc.cluster.local
2021-08-02 12:17:30,978 INFO common.Storage: Analyzing storage directories for bpid BP-1854773598-10.32.0.21-1627895491824
2021-08-02 12:17:30,978 INFO common.Storage: Locking is disabled for /hadoop/dfs/data/current/BP-1854773598-10.32.0.21-1627895491824
2021-08-02 12:17:31,445 INFO datanode.DataNode: Setting up storage: nsid=982693042;bpid=BP-1854773598-10.32.0.21-1627895491824;lv=-57;nsInfo=lv=-65;cid=CID-080a4fec-11de-48d9-be9e-645d2655fa7e;nsid=982693042;c=1627895491824;bpid=BP-1854773598-10.32.0.21-1627895491824;dnuuid=6def0bcc-f4e8-45a6-99c3-6710be17351b
2021-08-02 12:17:31,691 INFO impl.FsDatasetImpl: Added new volume: DS-a4e899e1-656e-4115-919b-fae25c51846b
2021-08-02 12:17:31,691 INFO impl.FsDatasetImpl: Added volume - [DISK]file:/hadoop/dfs/data, StorageType: DISK
2021-08-02 12:17:31,701 INFO impl.FsDatasetImpl: Registered FSDatasetState MBean
2021-08-02 12:17:31,724 INFO checker.ThrottledAsyncChecker: Scheduling a check for /hadoop/dfs/data
2021-08-02 12:17:31,745 INFO checker.DatasetVolumeChecker: Scheduled health check for volume /hadoop/dfs/data
2021-08-02 12:17:31,748 INFO impl.FsDatasetImpl: Adding block pool BP-1854773598-10.32.0.21-1627895491824
2021-08-02 12:17:31,750 INFO impl.FsDatasetImpl: Scanning block pool BP-1854773598-10.32.0.21-1627895491824 on volume /hadoop/dfs/data...
2021-08-02 12:17:31,802 INFO impl.FsDatasetImpl: Cached dfsUsed found for /hadoop/dfs/data/current/BP-1854773598-10.32.0.21-1627895491824/current: 2048
2021-08-02 12:17:31,837 INFO impl.FsDatasetImpl: Time taken to scan block pool BP-1854773598-10.32.0.21-1627895491824 on /hadoop/dfs/data: 83ms
2021-08-02 12:17:31,838 INFO impl.FsDatasetImpl: Total time to scan all replicas for block pool BP-1854773598-10.32.0.21-1627895491824: 88ms
2021-08-02 12:17:31,843 INFO impl.FsDatasetImpl: Adding replicas to map for block pool BP-1854773598-10.32.0.21-1627895491824 on volume /hadoop/dfs/data...
2021-08-02 12:17:31,846 INFO impl.BlockPoolSlice: Replica Cache file: /hadoop/dfs/data/current/BP-1854773598-10.32.0.21-1627895491824/current/replicas doesn't exist
2021-08-02 12:17:31,850 INFO impl.FsDatasetImpl: Time to add replicas to map for block pool BP-1854773598-10.32.0.21-1627895491824 on volume /hadoop/dfs/data: 8ms
2021-08-02 12:17:31,851 INFO impl.FsDatasetImpl: Total time to add all replicas to map for block pool BP-1854773598-10.32.0.21-1627895491824: 10ms
2021-08-02 12:17:31,908 INFO datanode.VolumeScanner: VolumeScanner(/hadoop/dfs/data, DS-a4e899e1-656e-4115-919b-fae25c51846b): no suitable block pools found to scan.  Waiting 1804233458 ms.
2021-08-02 12:17:31,949 INFO datanode.DirectoryScanner: Periodic Directory Tree Verification scan starting at 8/2/21 1:56 PM with interval of 21600000ms
2021-08-02 12:17:31,967 INFO datanode.DataNode: Block pool BP-1854773598-10.32.0.21-1627895491824 (Datanode Uuid 6def0bcc-f4e8-45a6-99c3-6710be17351b) service to namenode/10.108.44.52:8020 beginning handshake with NN
2021-08-02 12:17:32,058 INFO datanode.DataNode: Block pool Block pool BP-1854773598-10.32.0.21-1627895491824 (Datanode Uuid 6def0bcc-f4e8-45a6-99c3-6710be17351b) service to namenode/10.108.44.52:8020 successfully registered with NN
2021-08-02 12:17:32,058 INFO datanode.DataNode: For namenode namenode/10.108.44.52:8020 using BLOCKREPORT_INTERVAL of 21600000msec CACHEREPORT_INTERVAL of 10000msec Initial delay: 0msec; heartBeatInterval=3000
2021-08-02 12:17:32,298 INFO datanode.DataNode: Successfully sent block report 0xe102947467610cac,  containing 1 storage report(s), of which we sent 1. The reports had 0 total blocks and used 1 RPC(s). This took 11 msec to generate and 62 msecs for RPC and NN processing. Got back one command: FinalizeCommand/5.
2021-08-02 12:17:32,298 INFO datanode.DataNode: Got finalize command for block pool BP-1854773598-10.32.0.21-1627895491824
2021-08-02 12:21:56,012 WARN datanode.DataNode: Block pool BP-1854773598-10.32.0.21-1627895491824 (Datanode Uuid 6def0bcc-f4e8-45a6-99c3-6710be17351b) service to namenode/10.108.44.52:8020 is shutting down
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.UnregisteredNodeException): Unregistered server: DatanodeRegistration(10.47.0.0:9866, datanodeUuid=6def0bcc-f4e8-45a6-99c3-6710be17351b, infoPort=9864, infoSecurePort=0, ipcPort=9867, storageInfo=lv=-57;cid=CID-080a4fec-11de-48d9-be9e-645d2655fa7e;nsid=982693042;c=1627895491824)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.verifyRequest(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1704)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.sendHeartbeat(NameNodeRpcServer.java:1552)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.DatanodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.sendHeartbeat(DatanodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:119)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.DatanodeProtocolProtos$DatanodeProtocolService$2.callBlockingMethod(DatanodeProtocolProtos.java:31662)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:528)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:1070)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:999)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$RpcCall.run(Server.java:927)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2915)

        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getRpcResponse(Client.java:1545)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1388)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:233)
        at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:118)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy16.sendHeartbeat(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.DatanodeProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.sendHeartbeat(DatanodeProtocolClientSideTranslatorPB.java:168)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.sendHeartBeat(BPServiceActor.java:517)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.offerService(BPServiceActor.java:648)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:849)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-08-02 12:21:56,015 WARN datanode.DataNode: Ending block pool service for: Block pool BP-1854773598-10.32.0.21-1627895491824 (Datanode Uuid 6def0bcc-f4e8-45a6-99c3-6710be17351b) service to namenode/10.108.44.52:8020
2021-08-02 12:21:56,120 INFO datanode.DataNode: Removed Block pool BP-1854773598-10.32.0.21-1627895491824 (Datanode Uuid 6def0bcc-f4e8-45a6-99c3-6710be17351b)
2021-08-02 12:21:56,121 INFO impl.FsDatasetImpl: Removing block pool BP-1854773598-10.32.0.21-1627895491824
2021-08-02 12:21:59,466 WARN impl.FsDatasetImpl: Lock held time above threshold: lock identifier: org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl lockHeldTimeMs=3344 ms. Suppressed 0 lock warnings. The stack trace is: java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:1559)
org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.getStackTrace(StringUtils.java:1032)
org.apache.hadoop.util.InstrumentedLock.logWarning(InstrumentedLock.java:148)
org.apache.hadoop.util.InstrumentedLock.check(InstrumentedLock.java:186)
org.apache.hadoop.util.InstrumentedLock.unlock(InstrumentedLock.java:133)
org.apache.hadoop.util.AutoCloseableLock.release(AutoCloseableLock.java:84)
org.apache.hadoop.util.AutoCloseableLock.close(AutoCloseableLock.java:96)
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.fsdataset.impl.FsDatasetImpl.shutdownBlockPool(FsDatasetImpl.java:2819)
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.shutdownBlockPool(DataNode.java:1644)
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPOfferService.shutdownActor(BPOfferService.java:473)
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.cleanUp(BPServiceActor.java:594)
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.BPServiceActor.run(BPServiceActor.java:861)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2021-08-02 12:21:59,467 WARN fs.CachingGetSpaceUsed: Thread Interrupted waiting to refresh disk information: sleep interrupted
2021-08-02 12:22:01,468 WARN datanode.DataNode: Exiting Datanode
2021-08-02 12:22:01,492 INFO datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at datanode-1.datanode.hdfs.svc.cluster.local/10.36.0.0
************************************************************/
```

And the yaml file for my DataNode is:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: {{.Values.datanode.name}}
  namespace: {{.Values.namespace}}
spec:
  serviceName: "{{.Values.datanode.service.name}}"
  replicas: {{.Values.datanode.replicas}}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{.Values.datanode.name}}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{.Values.datanode.name}}
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
                - key: "app"
                  operator: In
                  values:
                  - {{.Values.datanode.name}}
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: CORE_CONF_fs_defaultFS
          value: hdfs://namenode:8020
        - name: CORE_CONF_hadoop_http_staticuser_user
          value: root
        - name: CORE_CONF_hadoop_proxyuser_hue_groups
          value: '*'
        - name: CORE_CONF_hadoop_proxyuser_hue_hosts
          value: '*'
        - name: CORE_CONF_hadoop_proxyuser_zeppelin_groups
          value: '*'
        - name: CORE_CONF_hadoop_proxyuser_zeppelin_hosts
          value: '*'
        - name: CORE_CONF_io_compression_codecs
          value: org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec
        - name: CORE_CONF_ha_zookeeper_quorum
          value: zookepper-0:2181,zookepper-1:2181,zookepper-2:2181
        - name: HDFS_CONF_dfs_namenode_acls_enabled
          value: ' true'
        - name: HDFS_CONF_dfs_namenode_datanode_registration_ip___hostname___check
          value: "false"
        - name: HDFS_CONF_dfs_permissions_enabled
          value: "false"
        - name: HDFS_CONF_dfs_replication
          value: "6"
        - name: HDFS_CONF_dfs_webhdfs_enabled
          value: "true"
        - name: HDFS_CONF_dfs_ha_automatic-failover_enabled
          value: "true"
        - name: HIVE_SITE_CONF_datanucleus_autoCreateSchema
          value: "false"
        - name: HIVE_SITE_CONF_hive_metastore_uris
          value: thrift://hive-metastore:9083
        - name: HIVE_SITE_CONF_javax_jdo_option_ConnectionDriverName
          value: org.postgresql.Driver
        - name: HIVE_SITE_CONF_javax_jdo_option_ConnectionPassword
          value: hive
        - name: HIVE_SITE_CONF_javax_jdo_option_ConnectionURL
          value: jdbc:postgresql://hive-metastore-postgresql/metastore
        - name: HIVE_SITE_CONF_javax_jdo_option_ConnectionUserName
          value: hive
        - name: MAPRED_CONF_mapred_child_java_opts
          value: -Xmx4096m
        - name: MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_framework_name
          value: yarn
        - name: MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_map_env
          value: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/
        - name: MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_map_java_opts
          value: -Xmx3072m
        - name: MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_map_memory_mb
          value: "4096"
        - name: MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_reduce_env
          value: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/
        - name: MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_reduce_java_opts
          value: -Xmx6144m
        - name: MAPRED_CONF_mapreduce_reduce_memory_mb
          value: "8192"
        - name: MAPRED_CONF_yarn_app_mapreduce_am_env
          value: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.2.1/
        - name: SERVICE_PRECONDITION
          value: namenode:9870
        - name: YARN_CONF_mapred_map_output_compress_codec
          value: org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.SnappyCodec
        - name: YARN_CONF_mapreduce_map_output_compress
          value: "true"
        - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_log___aggregation___enable
          value: "true"
        - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_log_server_url
          value: http://historyserver:8188/applicationhistory/logs/
        - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_nodemanager_aux___services
          value: mapreduce_shuffle
        - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_nodemanager_disk___health___checker_max___disk___utilization___per___disk___percentage
          value: "98.5"
        - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_nodemanager_remote___app___log___dir
          value: /app-logs
        - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_nodemanager_resource_cpu___vcores
          value: "8"
        - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_nodemanager_resource_memory___mb
          value: "16384"
        - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_address
          value: resourcemanager:8032
        - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_fs_state___store_uri
          value: /rmstate
        - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_hostname
          value: resourcemanager
        - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_recovery_enabled
          value: "true"
        - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_resource__tracker_address
          value: resourcemanager:8031
        - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_scheduler_address
          value: resourcemanager:8030
        - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_scheduler_class
          value: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler
        - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_store_class
          value: org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.recovery.FileSystemRMStateStore
        - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_resourcemanager_system___metrics___publisher_enabled
          value: "true"
        - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_scheduler_capacity_root_default_maximum___allocation___mb
          value: "8192"
        - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_scheduler_capacity_root_default_maximum___allocation___vcores
          value: "4"
        - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_timeline___service_enabled
          value: "true"
        - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_timeline___service_generic___application___history_enabled
          value: "true"
        - name: YARN_CONF_yarn_timeline___service_hostname
          value: historyserver
        image: {{.Values.datanode.image}}
        name: {{.Values.datanode.name}}
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9864
        - containerPort: 50075
        resources: {}
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /hadoop/dfs/data
          name: datanode
      restartPolicy: Always
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: datanode
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteMany"]
      storageClassName: {{.Values.storageClassName}}
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi


status:
  replicas: {{.Values.namenode.replicas}}
```

Comment: share your configuration details how you are setting up the cluster using helm chart or any github link if you have used any for ref .

Comment: I am using the helm Chart for hdfs Cluster.

Comment: can please share the helm link or details so that someone reading this question get an idea of what you configured. Also, share config details if you have done any tweaks.

Comment: I have shared the yaml file for datanode.

Comment: logs are important, you should keep that alos and just add the helm link and config details if you have changed any